# cannot resolve method setReverseLayout and setStackFromEnd?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to start my recyclerview itens from the bottom, so I tryed:

```
//Initializing Views
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewLf);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

the problem is setReverseLayout and setStackFromEnd cannot resolve method ... boolean.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Change

RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

to

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);